# Why is GitHub so much faster than a self hosted repository?

Tags: git, performance, github

Since git is a distributed version control system I want to host my primary repository myself. In the process of trying out different solutions I used both [gogs](https://gogs.io/) and [Apache2 + git-http-backend](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Smart-HTTP) on a quite beefy server (16 GiB RAM, SSD, quad core Xenon).

Before moving on I cloned the [freebsd-ports](https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd-ports) (~900 MiB size, 400k commits) repository and pushed it to both gogs and git-http-backend.

It took gogs more than 24 hours to process the push request. Browsing the commited repository in gogs takes several seconds per click. Afterwards I tried a plain Apache2 + git-http-backend setup. The push is still running, 3+ hours in.

Therefore I ask you: what does GitHub do to be so much faster? I thought pushing and browsing repositories should be nearly no-opts in git?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it asks us to speculate about the inner-workings of a proprietary cloud service.

Comment: You're missing the most important information in order to give an answer: How long did it take for you to push a ~900 MiB repo to GitHub? I.e. one that did not exist on GitHub before. Because while Git is distributed, it's *not* distributed across boundaries of different hosting services. I.e. the initial push to gogs or your own server both need to transfer the full repository.

Comment: @sschuberth you are right, I will try that. Of cause I forked the repo on GitHub but now that I think about it I must not do that. GitHub must not know the repository otherwise it could do a shallow copy

Comment: @ooxi And a "shallow copy" is indeed what GitHub does for a fork in order to save server-side disk space. A fork stores only the difference to upstream (plus some meta-data).

Comment: Because that there job to do perf optimisations: http://githubengineering.com/counting-objects/

Comment: Since everything is hashed, gitHub can probably just symlink stuff, or keep everything in the same git object storage thingy.

Comment: A push to GitHub took about ten minutes (not including upload time).